Jmeter how do I know my 1000 user test is a real test for 1000 actual users?
When we are running our Jmeter test we are testing 100-1000 users, but how close is that to actual 1000 users on our website? Is there ways to ensure that our script is very close to 1000 users?  Is there tools or ways to better ensure that I can tell my company that that our website can handle 1000 users?
We were watching our web servers and SQL server and saw results in task manager.

From JMeter perspective you can:

Observe the number of active threads (virtual users) using Active Threads Over Time listener or the equivalent chart of the HTML Reporting Dashboard

Make sure that JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser including:

handling embedded resources and cache
handling cookies and other headers
simulating AJAX requests
simulating real user's think time
other stuff like users distribution, non-HTTP protocols like WebSockets or SSE

in other words well-behaved JMeter test must produce the same network footprint as the real user using the real browser does, in this case you will have the confidence that the system under test supports that many users as you used for the load test


